# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel works in local debug but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, x509

I came across a lot of similar discussions, but none worked for me, so creating a new question.

I have an application (essentially a web service client) that accesses a web service using a server provided .p12 cert to establish a secure channel. I am successfully able to access this web service when I test it in the local environment and on azure. But when I publish this to my windows server (Windows Server 2012 R2), I am getting the below error.

### What I am trying to do:

```
    XElement ele;
    *WebServiceClientName* request;
    public RequestWebServiceFn()
    {
      request = new *WebServiceClientName*("*Service_instance_name_from_config_file*");
    }
    public XElement RequestWebServiceFn(string XMLFile)
    {
            ele = XElement.Parse(XMLFile);

            X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "*ThumbPrint*", false);
            // Get the first cert with the thumbprint
            if (certCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
                //write log to check correct cert
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("Log.txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now);
                    sw.WriteLine(cert.ToString());
                }
                // Use certificate
                request.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(cert.SubjectName.Name, certStore.Location, StoreName.My);
            }
            certStore.Close();

            try
            {
                XElement theResponse = request.serviceProcessor(ele);
                return theResponse;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("Log.txt"))
                {
                    var response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                    sw.WriteLine("HTTP Status Code: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
                }
//dummy return value since all codes paths need to return a value -this is not final version of the code, so it will be edited to prevent this step later
                XElement dddd = null;
                return dddd;
    } // catch block is never hit
```

### I have already tried

- granting certificate permissions to the current user and the local computer
- making the key exportable
- using the winHttp tool to grant the same accesses
- manipulate timeouts and explicitly setting security protocol to TlS/SSL in the codebehind

### The Error I am getting:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> Source Error: 
>        An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>        Stack Trace:
>
> [WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.] System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1686
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +74
>   [SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'aimws.agriculture.gov.ie'.]
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14807022
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) +386
>        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11738148 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +150 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1661

### Update:

As suggested by Pepo, and since this is a generic error, I enabled the CAPI2 error logs and found out that this was an issue with building of the certificate chain. The error log is:

> Log Name:     Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational
>   Source:       Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2
>   Date:          8/2/2018 6:21:20 AM
>   Event ID:      11
>   Task Category: Build Chain
>   Level:         Error
>   Keywords:      Path Discovery,Path Validation
>   User:          IIS
>   APPPOOL*poolName*
>   Computer:      ****
>
> Description:   For more details for this event, please refer to the
>   "Details" section   Event Xml:
>
> ```
> <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">  
>   <System>  
>     <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2" Guid="{5bbca4a8-b209-48dc-a8c7-b23d3e5216fb}" />  
>     <EventID>11</EventID>  
>     <Version>0</Version>  
>     <Level>2</Level>
>     <Task>11</Task>
>     <Opcode>2</Opcode>
>     <Keywords>0x4000000000000003</Keywords>
>     <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-08-02T11:21:20.466883100Z" />
>     <EventRecordID>7380</EventRecordID>
>     <Correlation />
>     <Execution ProcessID="7652" ThreadID="5284" />
>     <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational</Channel>
>     <Computer>****.****.eu</Computer>
>     <Security UserID="S-1-5-82-2597866206-523841173-4039190950-1604752381-3119016774"/>
>   </System>
>   <UserData>
>     <CertGetCertificateChain>
>       <Certificate fileRef="*Thumbnail*.cer" subjectName="****" />
>       <ValidationTime>2018-08-02T11:21:20.466Z</ValidationTime>
>       <ExtendedKeyUsage />
>       <Flags value="0" />
>       <ChainEngineInfo context="user" />
>       <AdditionalInfo>
>         <NetworkConnectivityStatus value="1" _SENSAPI_NETWORK_ALIVE_LAN="true" />
>       </AdditionalInfo>
>       <CertificateChain chainRef="{5ABF5961-50DF-48EE-B1F1-F4FA348098EB}">
>         <TrustStatus>
>           <ErrorStatus value="10000" CERT_TRUST_IS_PARTIAL_CHAIN="true" />
>           <InfoStatus value="0" />
>         </TrustStatus>
>         <ChainElement>
>           <Certificate fileRef="*Thumbnail*.cer" subjectName="****" />
>           <SignatureAlgorithm oid="1.2.840.113549.1.1.11" hashName="SHA256" publicKeyName="RSA" />
>           <PublicKeyAlgorithm oid="1.2.840.113549.1.1.1" publicKeyName="RSA" publicKeyLength="2048" />
>           <TrustStatus>
>             <ErrorStatus value="0" />
>             <InfoStatus value="1" CERT_TRUST_HAS_EXACT_MATCH_ISSUER="true" />
>           </TrustStatus>
>           <ApplicationUsage any="true" />
>           <IssuanceUsage />
>         </ChainElement>
>       </CertificateChain>
>       <EventAuxInfo ProcessName="w3wp.exe" />
>       <CorrelationAuxInfo TaskId="{D2A4C876-5EF0-48A2-9370-9A4950C13575}" SeqNumber="3" />
>       <Result value="800B010A">A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.</Result>
>     </CertGetCertificateChain>
>   </UserData>
> </Event>
> ```
>
> Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational
>   Source:        Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2
>   Date:          8/2/2018 6:21:20 AM
>   EventID:      30
>   Task Category: Verify Chain Policy
>   Level:        2 Error
>   Keywords:      Path Validation
>   User:          IISAPPPOOL*poolName*
>   Computer:      ****
>   Description:
>
> For more details for this event, please refer to the "Details" section   Event Xml:
>
> ```
> <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
>   <System>
>     <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2" Guid="{5bbca4a8-b209-48dc-a8c7-b23d3e5216fb}" />
>     <EventID>30</EventID>
>     <Version>0</Version>
>     <Level>2</Level>
>     <Task>30</Task>
>     <Opcode>0</Opcode>
>     <Keywords>0x4000000000000001</Keywords>
>     <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-08-02T11:21:20.341874100Z" />
>     <EventRecordID>7377</EventRecordID>
>     <Correlation />
>     <Execution ProcessID="7652" ThreadID="5284" />
>     <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational</Channel>
>     <Computer>****.****.eu</Computer>
>     <Security UserID="S-1-5-82-2597866206-523841173-4039190950-1604752381-3119016774"/>
>   </System>
>   <UserData>
>     <CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy>
>       <Policy type="CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_BASE" constant="1" />
>       <Certificate fileRef="*Thumbnail*.cer" subjectName="****" />
>       <CertificateChain chainRef="{F4FEE71D-659F-4F6A-BD90-77BC7F8451B0}" />
>       <Flags value="0" />
>       <Status chainIndex="0" elementIndex="-1" />
>       <EventAuxInfo ProcessName="w3wp.exe" />
>       <CorrelationAuxInfo TaskId="{50183916-F6E3-4F0A-B9F6-BB32B3667B06}" SeqNumber="1" />
>       <Result value="800B010A">A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.</Result>
>     </CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy>
>   </UserData>
> </Event>
> ```

Comment: what did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: well... what is the inner exception? does that endpoint exist? is it using TLS? is the certificate value? all sorts of things that only you can check...

Comment: Hi Kenneth and Marc
I have tried editing permissions, making key exportable, winHttp tool to grant access, manipulate timeouts and explicitly setting security protocol to Tls/SSL.
The endpoint exists because I have been testing it on the local computer plus on azure for a month now and it has always worked. It just doesn't seem to work when I host it on a windows server. The certificate is valid and is picking up correctly, I know this because again,  I logged the certificate it was picking up and confirmed it to be the correct certificate

Answer (score 0):

What I do in these cases is:

1. try it in internet explorer with client certificate installed in CurrentUser\My store.
2. try enabling CAPI2 event log to see what has been trying to verify, what certificate chain was it trying to build, what CRL was it trying to fetch etc.
3. Try openssl `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443`

If 1) fails you don't trust server certificate. Maybe intermediate CA or root CA is missing in certificate store.

If 2) fails you will see what it is. Maybe CRL is not accessible. Maybe some SSL/TLS inspection is breaking your mutual SSL/TLS authentication (like ESET antivirus does or WAF etc.)

3) will tell tell you what algorithms did the server offer and what client certificates does the server accept.

Comment: Thanks,
Enabled the CAPI2 log and could see that "A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority." Double checked that the certificate on the client side is added to the trusted root authority. Do not have access to the cert issuer server, so will get in touch with the people who do.
What I don't understand is why this issue does not occur in local host or azure, why only when hosting the client on Windows Server (It is a 2012 R2)

Comment: I don't know either :) At least you found the cause. The fix should be easy now.